# How to implement custom capes for minecraft 1.16.4 forge mod

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I need help. I want to make cape system for my forge mod e.g. custom capes for developers, donators, etc. I don't know how to do it or even if this is possible. If it's possible please tell me how to do it. The best solution would be if I can upload custom cape textures and assign them with UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two things that may or may not answer your question.

1: [This capes mod](https://minecraftcapes.net/) may help, or

2: Try reverse-engineering Optifine, and stealing the code used for their donator capes system. (I'm sure it's legal.)
I'm sorry I'm not of more help, but I don't know that much about Java or modding Minecraft. I'm just starting to get into using Socket on Python. But I want to try to learn it, eventually.